# How to edit Relationship properties to only use part of the CDM Identifier in LDM?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, powerdesigner

I'm creating a conceptual data model for a simplified web store using Power Designer.

I'm having trouble specifying the relation between an **Order** and a **Receipt**. I would like a receipt to only have a part of the order's identifier in its primary key in the logical model (more specifically, only `order_id`). I am unable to achieve this by tweaking the relationship properties (see the screenshots bellow; the problematic relationship is marked with a green arrow).

Should I simply omit the relation in the conceptual model?

---

### Conceptual data model

[image]

### Logical data model

[image]

### EDIT

If perhaps it wasn't clear how I envisioned my tables…

**User**

| username | password | mail | first_name | last_name | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hacker123 | greenGrass | david.norton@gmail.com | David | Norton | West Shire 40, 1240 Neverland |
| musicman100 | SuperPassword | john.stewart@gmail.com | John | Stewart | Strange Alley 50, 1250 Outer Space |

**Product**

| product_id | name | description | price_per_unit | unit_of_measure | supply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tooth Brush 100 | NULL | 5.99 | piece | 200 |
| 2 | Super Paste 200 | For sparkling smiles | 7.99 | piece | 50 |

**Order**

| order_id | username | product_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | hacker123 | 1 | 2 |
| 50 | hacker123 | 2 | 1 |
| 51 | musicman100 | 1 | 5 |

**Receipt**

| receipt_id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 50 |
| 13 | 51 |

### EDIT #2

I just realised that I should probably break up Order into two tables! One to track which products are on a particular order, and another to track who placed the order.

Perhaps I could even split the Order table into 3 parts

`Order(order_id, order_time)`

`ProductsPerOrder(order_id, product_id, amount)`

`OrdersPlaced(order_id, username)`

Answer (score 1):

You have a contradiction... One part says that Order is identified by User+Product+Order; the other says that Order has its own identifier order_id.

I guess the second one is correct, with the usual design that Order has an id.

And you need to change the relationships in the CDM, between Order, and User/Product, to **uncheck the Dependent** property. These links are just mandatory, not dependent (which would mean that Order is defined relatively to User+Product).

p.s. the same holds for Receipt, which has its own identifier.

Comment: Either order_id is an identifier, and user_id, product_id are redundant in Order primary key (which reminds me of lessons on Second Normal Form from decades ago). Or it's relative to user_id+product_id (more probably, relative to user_id, with a sequential number to keep track of the N-th order from this customer), and you need user_id+product_id in Receipt...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do with my question now. On the one hand, I've found a way to circumvent poor design, but your answer made me redesign my model, effectively making my original answer obsolete.

Comment: Leave your question as it is... It can trigger an aha moment for someone else...

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the relationship in the *logical model*!

If you click on a relationship, a [*Relationship properties*](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_pd1655_data/16.5.5/en-US/c7/c3dc1c6e1b1014a4a4db61b5ac0ca3/frameset.htm) dialog appears. There's a tab called ***Joins***. This is where you can specify which columns to refer to with the relationship.